# mobaxterm - having trouble with compiling C and C++

Tags: terminal, compilation

I get the following errors when I try to compile a c/c++ program in Mobaxterm.

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the advapi32.dll, shell32,dll, user32.dll, and kernel32.dll in my system32 folder in the C drive. However, I am not sure how to make the terminal look there to find the .dll files. How do I fix this?
Please let me know if there is additional information you would like me to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because sometimes in Mobaxterm, the libraries are downloaded in the wrong order, which causes some of the files to not be included. When a library is downloaded, it checks if the folder is already there, if so, then it does not update. Try uninstalling and reinstalling mobaxterm, and download your necessary packages in a different order. It might vary from package to package.